# Get JSON from sql query that contains text MariaDB

Tags: sql, json, string, mariadb

Let's say I have a row called "weather" in a SQL table like ..
"Weather today is Sunny{"temp":"79","rainchance":"0%"}"

How would I get ONLY the json data?
Using MariaDB

I have tried 'JSON_VALUE(weather,'$.temp') as temperature', but this doesn't seem to work because of the string that precedes the JSON data.

Still learning, thanks!

Comment: Does the row values always come in the form of "text{json data}"? Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please tag with the database engine

Comment: @JoshPart yes, that's correct. It's always 'text:{"then":"json"}'
I only want the value of 'json'.

I am using MariaDB

Comment: just to have everything covered: are you using the right version of mariadb?

Comment: @JoshPart I'm using 10.3.27. Just to further clarify, if the cell only contains json, I am able to use JSON_VALUE(weather,'$.temp') as temperature. I guess what I need to do is ignore everything besides the JSON table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of substring() and instr() to strip out the JSON part. ie:

```
create table test (MyStr text);
insert into test (MyStr) 
  values ('Weather today is Sunny{"temp":"79","rainchance":"0%"}');

select JSON_VALUE(substring(mystr, instr(mystr,'{')),'$.temp')
from test;
```

PS: If it doesn't end with '}' then you could use substring_index() to get the desired part.

Comment: JSON_VALUE(substring(mystr, instr(mystr,'{')),'$.temp') did the trick! Thanks a ton